# Every Natbib's citing option (using plainnat) gives me a number between parenthesis instead of Author-year

Tags: natbib

I'm kind of new in LaTeX.

Every `natbib`'s citing option (using `plainnat`) gives me a number between parenthesis instead of Author-year.

I'm using `natbib` as package, `plainnat` as bibliographystyle, and `\citep{x}` as the citing command. I recompile and it gives me something like this `(7)`. It should give me something like this: `(McCain, 1990)`. When I use the `\citet{x}` command it gives me only the name `McCain`.

I'm using ShareLaTeX, a main `.tex` file that calls other `.tex` files (chapters), I'm citing in those other files. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without a proper MWE. Perhaps you load `natbib` like so `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`? In that case, remove the `numbers` option; otherwise, please compose a minimal, complete version of your document illustrating the problem and add it as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It works here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{article-full} \citet{article-minimal} \cite{whole-journal}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

[image: Natbib with plainnat]

As Gonzalo Medina points out, your question should include an MWE.